# Browsing 1 link and out another tabs with different links

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write codes in my blogger to show when I browsing link likes www.12345.blogspot.com(example) ,after loading inside ,it will auto out anothor tabs in browser to run links which set by me.
So, example is i typing link of www.12345.blogspot.com and press enter to browse and will out another tabs likes www.youtube.com ,the focus point in webpage still in first (www.12345.blogspot.com).

Any codes could write about what I describe? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when loading a website, you want to open a second website in a separate tab while maintaining focus on the first tab. Here's how you'd do it:

```
var w=window.open("https://google.ie");
if(w)w.blur();
```

I would, however, advise very strongly against doing this.

Comment: Does it auto pop out another tabs when I browse in first tab?

Comment: <script language='JavaScript'>
var w=window.open(&quot;https://www.youtube.com&quot;);
if(w)w.blur();
</script>
try in blogger already but didt pop out anything tabs when I browing my blogger

Comment: The quotation marks shouldn't be HTML entities. And you've omitted the protocol.

Comment: Can you write a full detail of coding???Because little not understand what you describe